# Derivative of sandwich product of Geometric Algebra rotor and vector wrt that rotor.

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-algebras, exterior-derivative

How do I find the derivative (differential?) of the sandwich product of a rotor, with respect to the rotor?

Namely, given a rotor $R$, and vector $v$, what is
$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}R}(Rv\tilde{R})$?

I've seen how this is done using matrix representations of quaternions, but I'd like to know how to do this staying in Geometric Algebra.  I'd like the answer as a (multi?)vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, with $F(R)$ a multivector-valued function of a multivector argument, the derivative of $F$ with respect to $R$ in the (multivector) direction $A$ is defined as

$$F_A(R)=\lim_{e\to 0}\frac{F(R+\epsilon A)-F(R)}{\epsilon}\ ,$$
with $\epsilon$ a real scalar.

The notation used for the directional derivative can vary by author, for example Doran and Lasenby would write $A*\partial_R F(R)$ instead of $F_A(R)$. And Hestenes and Sobczyk would describe $F_A(R)$ as the differential of $F$ at $R$ instead of calling it a directional derivative, when regarding $F_A(R)$ as a linear function of $A$.

In this case, the function in question is

$$F(R)=Rv\tilde{R}\ ,$$

where $v$ is a vector, and $\sim$ is the reversion operator (some authors use $\dagger$ instead of $\sim$). Plugging in this $F(R)$ into the definition of $F_A(R)$ we have:

$$F_A(R)=\lim_{e\to 0}\frac{(R+\epsilon A)v(R+\epsilon A)^\sim-Rv\tilde{R}}{\epsilon}=Av\tilde{R}+Rv\tilde{A}$$

For arbitrary multivectors $A$ and $B$, $(AB)^\sim=\tilde{B}\tilde{A}$, and the reverse of a vector is just the vector, so we can write

$$F_A(R)=Av\tilde{R}+(Av\tilde{R})^\sim\ .$$

With $M_r$ an arbitrary homogeneous multivector of grade $r$,

$$\tilde{M}_r=(-1)^{r(r-1)/2}M_r\ .$$

$Av\tilde{R}$ is a multivector consisting of odd grades, because $A$ and $\tilde{R}$ are even grade and $v$ is odd grade. And since the question is about an alternative perspective to quaternions, which are even-graded multivectors on a 3D Euclidean space, the highest grade that $Av\tilde{R}$ can contain is $3$. Thus, $Av\tilde{R}$ can only contain grades $1$ and $3$, so we can write

$$Av\tilde{R}=\langle Av\tilde{R} \rangle_1 + \langle Av\tilde{R} \rangle_3$$

and

$$(Av\tilde{R})^\sim=\langle Av\tilde{R} \rangle_1 - \langle Av\tilde{R} \rangle_3$$

Plugging those expressions into the equation for $F_A(R)$ gives the final result,

$$F_A(R)=2\langle Av\tilde{R} \rangle_1\ .$$

There also exists something called the multivector derivative, $\partial_R F$, which for this function just works out to $\partial_R F=6 v\tilde{R}$, but it doesn't seem to me like the multivector derivative would be nearly as useful as the differential for the sandwich product of a rotor. In particular, the matrix result you've seen for quaternions is presumably the Jacobian matrix, which is the matrix of the differential in some chosen basis.